# How to open the flash security setting when flash object on the page is less than the size of the dialogue

Tags: flash

If the window of flash player on the page is less than the size of the  security settings dialog from the context menu disappears item "Parameters...".

Dialogue also can't call from actionscript (Security.showSettings("privacy");).

What ways of solving this problem exist?

Comment: the security dialog is displayed by Flash - so if your Flash movie is smaller than the dialog box, part of the dialog box will be hidden - no way round that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve it another way, except resizing your swf. This is written somewhere in official Adobe guide for web-app development.